# job queue in windows service

Tags: c#, service, triggers

I need to create a windows service that processes a job queue.

A trigger will fill up the queue, and the windows service will process  that queue.

I know how to create a windows service (using a timer), but I'm not sure about how tell the trigger (CLR project) to fill the queue, and how to process it.

I'm new in C#, so any example, ideas, guidances are wellcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Bill Sambrone.

I found SQL Server Service Broker (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

It is a service that uses queues to send messages that are guaranteed to arrive to destiny, it can send messages between databases, remote databases, and also to external apps. I'm sending the messages to my c# external app. And the best is that it comes bundled inside SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a MQ (message queueing) system. Try looking into this (RabbitMQ) as a starting point, then update your question with specifics if need be.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

Here is Microsoft's implementation of it (MSMQ):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)